# Problems with Stylus on Meteor

Tags: meteor, stylus

I have building my first Meteor add following the "Discover Meteor" book.

But I got stuck now with the following error:

error: no plugin found for accounts_ui.styl in ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3; a plugin for *.styl was active when it was published but none is now

I believe this has to do with my current stylus package. It is currently running 1.0.7 and won't let me update to the latest version.

Upon updating I get this error:
error: Package name must contain a lowercase ASCII letter: "2.513.4"

It also won't install the latest version if I remove and add it again.

Any ideas are welcome.

Cheers, 
Dominic

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After searching for a while I actually found something that fixed this error.

I first had to remove both ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, accounts-password and stylus.

Then **first** add stylus (for some reason it would not install the latest version if not installed first).

Then add the other packages.

Happy coding!

Comment: Current ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 version seems to have some dependencies issues with stylus.

I had a similar issue to yours when I was getting the error: `error: no plugin found for accounts_ui.styl in ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3; a plugin for *.styl was active when it was published but none is now`

Note you can always solve package version issues (or update them) by editing .meteor/versions. In my particular case I've solved it by replacing the stylus line for `stylus@2.512.5`

Comment: Thanks for still adding this. I tried updating this plugin manually by typing update stylus and the version number but indeed, doing it via the meteor/versions would be a better idea. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's actually an issue with the stylus package. First try meteor remove ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, then meteor add stylus, then meteor add ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 ... This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**meteor update stylus** or **meteor update --all-packages** to update stylus to latest version.